# error 503:Packages.gz naming problem

Tags: apt, package-management, software-sources, naming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [error 503: service unavailable when using apt-get update behind proxy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26528/error-503-service-unavailable-when-using-apt-get-update-behind-proxy)

### Here is the detailed information(I have choosen the best source server):

```
 W:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  503
, W:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  503
, W:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  503
, W:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  503
, W:Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  503
, W:Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/source/Sources  503
, W:Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  503
, W:Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  503
, W:Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  503
, W:Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/binary-i386/Packages  503
, W:Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/source/Sources  503
, W:Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/source/Sources  503
, W:Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/source/Sources  503
, W:Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/source/Sources  503
, W:Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  503
, W:Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  503
, W:Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  503
, W:Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  503
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

> > *Notice:* 
> >     http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages 
> >      is not a valid url and  I can easily access
> >      http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.gz 
> >      from firefox or command line(like wget) without a proxy.
> >     Also I have tired one solution described here:
> >     answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+question/155500

```
hippo@dellsys:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 11.10 _Oneiric Ocelot_ - Release amd64 (20111012)]/ dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 11.10 _Oneiric Ocelot_ - Release amd64 (20111012)]/ oneiric main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
# deb http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted multiverse
# deb-src http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/ quantal restricted main universe multiverse #Added by software-properties

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
# deb http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted multiverse
# deb-src http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates restricted main universe multiverse #Added by software-properties
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/ quantal universe
# deb http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe
## wxwidgets part
# deb http://apt.wxwidgets.org/ natty-wx main # disabled on upgrade to quantal
# deb-src http://apt.wxwidgets.org/ natty-wx main # disabled on upgrade to quantal
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

# deb http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security main restricted multiverse
# deb-src http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security restricted main universe multiverse #Added by software-properties
# deb http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security universe

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu oneiric partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu oneiric partner
#xbmc
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu natty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu natty main
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
# deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu precise main
# deb-src http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu precise main
# deb http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports restricted main multiverse universe
# Remastersys
# deb http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/repository karmic/
# deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu precise main
# deb-src http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu precise main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tldm217/tahutek.net/ubuntu natty main*
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/tldm217/tahutek.net/ubuntu natty main*
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tldm217/tahutek.net/ubuntu natty main # disabled on upgrade to quantal
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/tldm217/tahutek.net/ubuntu natty main # disabled on upgrade to quantal
deb http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/ precise main universe
deb-src http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/ precise main universe #Added by software-properties
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security universe main
deb-src http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/ precise-security universe main #Added by software-properties
deb http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe main
deb-src http://ubuntu.cn99.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe main #Added by software-properties
```

You can see I minimized sources.list and other repositories. Still cannot make any progress in handling this problem.

> > Ubuntu12.04LTS,kernel 3.2.0-33-generic.Any suggestion is appreciate.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah,a proxy issue and the /var/lib/dpkg  directory broken,after using backup to restore these files all things work well.Thanks any way! :)